# determine if file can be created/is not readonly in C++

Tags: c++, c, file-io

How to check, if file can be created or data can be written to it? This is my code, but I think, it doesn't handle if the file is writeable...Could anybody please show me, how to do it?

```
bool joinFiles(const char * outFile) {
try {
    ofstream arrayData(outFile);
    //do something
    // ...
    //

    // write data
    arrayData << "blahblah" << endl;   

} catch (const char *ex) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: open file in write mode if it open you can write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to check, if file can be created or data can be written to it?

Streams do not throw exceptions by default (they can be configured to throw exceptions via [`std::basic_ios::exceptions()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions)) so check if the file has been opened, using [`std::ofstream::is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open):

```
ofstream arrayData(outFile);
if (arrayData.is_open())
{
    // File is writeable, but may not have existed
    // prior to the construction of 'arrayData'.

    // Check success of output operation also.
    if (arrayData << "blahblah" << endl)
    {
        // File was opened and was written to.
        return true;
    }
}
// File was not opened or the write to it failed.
return false;
```